# Words for 'escorting,' 'showing around': 带你出去 vs. 护送你出去 vs. 陪你去玩儿

Tags: mandarin, difference

> 带你出去...
>
> 护送你出去...
>
> 陪你去玩儿...

I am especially interested in the difference in meaning between the first and third. The third may not be correct because I may be recalling it poorly.

The first seems clear: "...to take you out" in the sense of escorting and showing around. But isn't there a similar meaning for "pei?" The second one is new to me and seems to have a similar meaning.

Comment: "陪" = accompany with

Answer (score 9, accepted):

带 has a sense of lead/host, A带B去 can be used in the situation where B doesn't know the place but A does, so A takes B there and shows him around.

陪 means accompany, it does not have the sense of lead/host. B陪A may be used in a situation where A may feel strange or uncomfortable with acting alone and wants somebody else to accompany him.

护送 means precisely escort, where 护 means 保护 (protect).

Answer (score 7):

I will give you three sentences, let’s see the difference:

1.我带你出去。
2.我护送你出去。
3.我陪你出去。

Sentence 1.： I take you out. So I will guide you and show you around.

Sentence 2:  I escort you out. May be “you “ are in danger, somebody could hurt “you” if “you” go out by yourself, so I will go out with you and protect you. “ 护送”can also used to modify things, like “ 护送钱”.

Sentence 3: I will go out with you.  Because “you” don’t want to go out by yourself, you will be lonely, so I will company you.